# Having an issue enabling internode TLS support in rabbitmq / erlang

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq, erlang

We are running rabbit v3.8.3-1.el7, erlang v23.3.3.el7, kernel 3.10.0-1062.12.1.el7.x86_64, release Centos 7.7

I have three nodes that I would like in disc mode, cdvlhbqr23[1-3]

However I'm running into an issue after attempting to enable TLS on erlang.

```
[ cdvlhbqr231:rabbitmq ]
10.128.3.231 :: root -> rabbitmqctl status
Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@cdvlhbqr231'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

Most common reasons for this are:

 * Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection or firewall issues)
 * CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
 * Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

 * See the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
 * Consult server logs on node rabbit@cdvlhbqr231
 * If target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@cdvlhbqr231]

rabbit@cdvlhbqr231:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on cdvlhbqr231
  * epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
  * TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
  * suggestion: check if the Erlang cookie identical for all server nodes and CLI tools
  * suggestion: check if all server nodes and CLI tools use consistent hostnames when addressing each other
  * suggestion: check if inter-node connections may be configured to use TLS. If so, all nodes and CLI tools must do that
   * suggestion: see the CLI, clustering and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more


Current node details:
 * node name: 'rabbitmqcli-23412-rabbit@cdvlhbqr231'
 * effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq/
 * Erlang cookie hash: MudCW7tn3FA5sTmC1FlR0g==
```

I've double checked the cookie file and it's identical across all nodes. All of the hostnames are correct and consistent across the nodes. So I assume this has to be directly the result of ssl / tls

Here's what the node config looks like:

```
[ cdvlhbqr231:rabbitmq ]
10.128.3.231 :: root -> cat /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
[
    {rabbit,
        [
            {vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.4},
            {vm_memory_high_watermark_paging_ratio, 0.5},
            {memory_alarms, true},
            {disk_free_limit, 41686528},
            {cluster_partition_handling, autoheal},
            {tcp_listen_options,
                [binary,
                    {packet, raw},
                    {reuseaddr, true},
                    {backlog, 128},
                    {nodelay, true},
                    {exit_on_close, false},
                    {keepalive, true}
                ]
            },
            {cluster_nodes, {['rabbit@cdvlhbqr231', 'rabbit@cdvlhbqr232', 'rabbit@cdvlhbqr233'], disc}},
            {loopback_users, []},
            {tcp_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0",5672}]},
            {ssl_listeners, [{"0.0.0.0",5671}]},
            {ssl_options, [
                {cacertfile,"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"},
                {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cert.pem"},
                {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/key.pem"},
                {verify,verify_peer},
                {versions, ['tlsv1.2']},
                {fail_if_no_peer_cert,false}
            ]}

        ]
    },
    {rabbitmq_management,
        [{
            listener, [
                {port, 15672},
                {ip, "0.0.0.0"},                
                {ssl, true},
                {ssl_opts, [
                    {cacertfile,"/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt"},
                    {certfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/cert.pem"},
                    {keyfile,"/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/key.pem"},
                    {verify,verify_peer},
                    {versions, ['tlsv1.2']}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]
    }
].
```

The private key is generated on the host and signed by an intermediate CA whose pub key is in the systems extracted cert bundle. We generate an "/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/allfile.pem" which is a bundle of the servers private key and signed cert.

The ssl environment for erlang is defined as the following:

```
[ cdvlhbqr231:rabbitmq ]
10.128.3.231 :: root -> cat rabbitmq-env.conf
# Obtaining of an Erlang ssl library path
export HOME=/var/lib/rabbitmq/
ERL_SSL_PATH=/usr/lib64/erlang/lib/ssl-9.6.2/ebin

# Add SSL-related environment vars for rabbitmq-server and rabbitmqctl
SERVER_ADDITIONAL_ERL_ARGS="-pa $ERL_SSL_PATH \
  -proto_dist inet_tls \
  -ssl_dist_opt server_certfile '/etc/rabbitmq/ssl/allfile.pem' \
  -ssl_dist_opt server_secure_renegotiate true client_secure_renegotiate true"

# CLI
CTL_ERL_ARGS="-pa $ERL_SSL_PATH \
  -proto_dist inet_tls \
  -ssl_dist_opt server_certfile /etc/rabbitmq/ssl/allfile.pem \
  -ssl_dist_opt server_secure_renegotiate true client_secure_renegotiate true"
```

I'm not entirely clear what's causing the issue. I thought I had followed the documentation to a T. Can anyone help me review this and see if there is anything obvious I'm missing, or any suggestions on how to trace down this problem?